# How to import qs in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, stringify

I searched about **［How to use qs in react］** but can't find the answer.

Qs's official site https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs
**Usage**

```
qs = require('qs');
var assert = require('assert');

var obj = qs.parse('a=c');
assert.deepEqual(obj, { a: 'c' });

var str = qs.stringify(obj);
assert.equal(str, 'a=c');
```

But I never see `require()` used in react.

Does anybody know this answer?

I need this for passing array parameter in axios.

Comment: ensure @types/qs is installed in your dev dependencies then you can call import qs from "qs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this identical problem in my React.

This would work:

```
const qs = require('qs')
```

This wouldnt work:

```
import qs from 'qs'
```

I solved it by deleting the "@types/qs" section from my package-lock.json, then running

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 17):

You don't have to uninstall `@types/qs` from your project. The correct solution is to use:

```js
import * as qs from 'qs'
```

Comment: This answer needs to be upvoted! It really works. Thank you.

Comment: This line should be at the top of the qs docs.

Answer (score 5):

This solved my problem

`npm i --save-dev @types/qs`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick note, in case someone reaches this thread from 2022 on.

Using this syntax works flawlessly on both React.js v18+ and Next.js v12+

```
import qs from 'qs';
```

Comment: Note this syntax was likely supported for @fcampusdev because they had `"esModuleInterop": true` in the `compilerOptions` section of their tsconfig.

Answer (score -3):

Run:

```
npm install qs
```

In your script, use:

```
import Qs from "qs";
```